# How do I get all resource paths in my bundle recursively in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an "unzipped" folder in my application bundle.  I need to get the resource paths for all files of type txt.  I've been using this,

```
NSArray *filePaths = [NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"txt" inDirectory:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/unzipped"]];
```

But it only gets files in the first directory.  Is there a recursive version of this somewhere that I'm just missing?

Comment: Your title says to get all resources paths, but the body says to only get txt so yeah a bit two sided. :-/ I came here looking for a way to get all files.

Comment: You should be able to do the same thing with the NSDirectoryEnumerator below, just remove the conditional that checks for the file type.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I got this working using the code posted by @rekle as a starting point.  The trick is to use NSDirectoryEnumerator, which will do this recursively.  Here's the function I wrote in case anyone needs it.

```
- (NSArray *)recursivePathsForResourcesOfType:(NSString *)type inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath{

    NSMutableArray *filePaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Enumerators are recursive
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:directoryPath] retain];

    NSString *filePath;

    while ((filePath = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil){

        // If we have the right type of file, add it to the list
        // Make sure to prepend the directory path
        if([[filePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:type]){
            [filePaths addObject:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath]];
        }
    }

    [enumerator release];

    return [filePaths autorelease];
}
```

---

**Swift, using `NSURL`**

```
func recursivePathsForResources(type type: String) -> [NSURL] {

    // Enumerators are recursive
    let enumerator = NSFileManager.defaultManager().enumeratorAtPath(bundlePath)
    var filePaths = [NSURL]()

    while let filePath = enumerator?.nextObject() as? String {

        if NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath).pathExtension == type {
            filePaths.append(bundleURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(filePath))
        }
    }

    return filePaths
}
```

Comment: please use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`

Answer (score 7):

Just an update to this method to allow any file types (nil) and provide the correct path format

```
- (NSArray *)recursivePathsForResourcesOfType:(NSString *)type inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath{

    NSMutableArray *filePaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:directoryPath];

    NSString *filePath;

    while ((filePath = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil){
        if (!type || [[filePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:type]){
            [filePaths addObject:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath]];
        }
    }

    return filePaths;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePath error:&error];
```

'files' will be an array of strings containing all the filenames in that path...

Comment: That gets all files, not just txt files, which is to be expected.  but it doesn't recurse through the directories.

Comment: Does not recursively visit all directories within provided path.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.1 version of the [answer from smokinggoyster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5860015/156210)

```
func recursivePathsForResources(type: String, in directoryPath: String) -> [String] {
    // Enumerators are recursive
    let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: directoryPath)
    var filePaths: [String] = []

    while let filePath = enumerator?.nextObject() as? String {

        if URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath).pathExtension == type {
            filePaths.append(directoryPath.byAppending(pathComponent: filePath))
        }
    }
    return filePaths
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before copying think about create symlink. You can create just **one** symlink to folder with a lot of items.
And it will work in most situations.

You will be free from creating another thread, waiting for end of operation, etc.