# Core Data Bad Access insertNewObjectForEntityForName issue

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have bad access issue in core data while insert data in database and I also used @try,@catch block but I can't find any solution for the same. I am stuck for last 3days so please help me for solve this issue or give me any suggestion.

```
- (BOOL) addSynchedContactsList:(int)aAppContactId :(NSString*)aDevContactId
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] managedObjectContext];
    BOOL success = YES;

    ContactsListSync *syncContact = (ContactsListSync *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_CONTACTSLISTSYNC inManagedObjectContext:context];

    syncContact.appContactlistId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:aAppContactId];
    syncContact.devConatctlistId = aDevContactId;

    return success;
}
```

In this line,

**ContactsListSync *syncContact = (ContactsListSync *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_CONTACTSLISTSYNC inManagedObjectContext:context];**

OR

**ContactsListSync *syncContact = (ContactsListSync *)[[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_CONTACTSLISTSYNC inManagedObjectContext:context] retain];**

So Please give me any suggestion or any idea.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16750569/1603072) ?

Comment: @Vin thanks but I have already try it.

Comment: @NikunjJadav: are you using one managed object context?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko I have one manageObjectContext for one method and this  one is globally context [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] managedObjectContext];

Comment: @NikunjJadav: Can you make sure that the context is used only on the main thread?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko yes its used only on main thread [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] managedObjectContext]

Comment: @NikunjJadav: on what line it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko I already mention in my question so plz see it

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger. Make sure you have a valid context.

Answer (score 1):

Put a break point at the first line and step through each.
 I would be checking for the following:

- context is a valid context (hover over or type po context after assignment)
- ENTITY_CONTACTSLISTSYNC resolve to a valid entity name
- aAppContactId and aDevContactId are valid values

Check ContactListSync Entity for required fields not provided?

If it is failing at the third line, seems would be one of three things, context invalid, context on another thread, entity name incorrect. What clues do you get in the error message at exception?

Comment: thanks a lot for help all fields are optional, context are also valid with value and also valid entity name but I think that insert contacts in core data from device native contact and I used mainObjectContext for that one in background