# App crashes with SQLite error after updating from appstore

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, core-data-migration

After updating application from Appstore it always crashes. The error I get is,

```
The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store already updated app
```

To fix this I've followed the steps explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17475215/2842382). After this fix I face new error,

```
Can't find model for source store.
```

In the updated version of my app, I've just changed some attributes from `integer 16` to `integer 32`, nothing more. I don't know any other workaround to fix this crash happening for my users. If user deletes the older version of app and then installs the latest one, it works fine.

Any pointers on how to fix the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to migrate the core data to the newer model via versioning.Refer the link http://9elements.com/io/index.php/customizing-core-data-migrations/

Answer (score 0):

Did you use auto mapping? (As demonstrating in the link you posted). If so, as the previous poster mentioned, you have to create a new model version -- click on your model, edit "new model", based on your current model.  The new model is the one you want to make changes to otherwise your app will crash. Do not change your current live model.

When you say "if users delete the current version" are you talking about beta users or App Store users?