# abort method error when deleting model class

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

In my simple project I have a core data model file and in this model file I have an entity called "Target", I created a subclass of NSManagedObject to this entity so I can persist data. So now I have a `.h` and `.m` Target class files with just two attributes:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Target : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * body;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * time;

@end
```

Now I want to add to this class 2 more properties so I read about it and gave it few tries with some techniques but each one will give me the same error which is:

[image]

How do I get rid of the error "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"?

Comment: Don't post screenshot of your error, show us directly the text error.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881453/the-model-used-to-open-the-store-is-incompatible-with-the-one-used-to-create-the

Comment: Those 2 properties are you adding at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting ur application from simulator/device. And try to build and run it again.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever u modify the entity like adding attributes/removing/modifying u need to remove the app from simulator/device and then u need to run the app to avoid crash..

Else If ur app is in App Store and If u want to add more properties to existing app u need to do Core Data Migration..

Refer below links

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2150667&seqNum=2

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-migrations--cms-21844

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall application from your simulator/device then install again. This crush happening because of what type of migration or store option your are giving while adding `NSPersistentStore` with `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` object.

Try to read about migration from

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Migration_Options