# Swift SIGBART threat CoreData

Tags: multithreading, core-data, swift2, xcode7.2

I have the problem about SIGBART. i did google it and try to solve it.

but i only have it on one of my buttons.

This is how my tool bar said.

> CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite
>   configuration:(null)
>   URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D223A294-3617-494F-8774-9CA6DCB61C2D/Documents/SingleViewCoreData.sqlite
>   options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=134100 "The managed object model version used to open the
>   persistent store is incompatible with the one that was used to create
>   the persistent store." UserInfo={metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 637;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Item = ;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "7711BB5D-CAF4-4F2E-9122-AF54B74D3850";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2; }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store} with
>   userInfo dictionary {
>       metadata =     {
>           NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 637;
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
>               Item = ;
>           };
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>           NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
>               ""
>           );
>           NSStoreType = SQLite;
>           NSStoreUUID = "7711BB5D-CAF4-4F2E-9122-AF54B74D3850";
>           "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
>       };
>       reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"; } 2016-01-07 12:18:39.271
>   test7[2483:1077844] Unresolved error Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN
>   Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the
>   application's saved data, NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error
>   creating or loading the application's saved data.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x134e63a80 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=134100 "The managed object model version used to open the
>   persistent store is incompatible with the one that was used to create
>   the persistent store." UserInfo={metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 637;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Item = ;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "7711BB5D-CAF4-4F2E-9122-AF54B74D3850";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2; }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}}},
>   [NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to initialize the application's saved
>   data, NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading
>   the application's saved data., NSUnderlyingError: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The managed object model
>   version used to open the persistent store is incompatible with the one
>   that was used to create the persistent store." UserInfo={metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 637;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Item = ;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "7711BB5D-CAF4-4F2E-9122-AF54B74D3850";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2; }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}] (lldb)

Code on board:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class RecordTVC: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate   {
let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

func fetchRequest() ->NSFetchRequest  {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "users")
    let sortDescriptior = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptior]

    return fetchRequest

}

func getFRC() ->NSFetchedResultsController {


    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return frc

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    frc = getFRC()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()

    }  catch {

    print("failed to perform fetch")

        return
    }
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 100

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    frc = getFRC()
    frc.delegate = self

    do  {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {

        print("failed to appear")
        return
    }
     self.tableView.reloadData()

}
   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            _ = frc.sections?.count

    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      _ = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
    return 0
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)




    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let users = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Users
    cell.textLabel?.text = users.name

    let date = users.data
    let note = users.note

    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = " Date: \(date!) Note: \(note!)"
    return cell
}
```

}

And on the appDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "mis-dentmate.com.tw.test7" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test7", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")

        abort()


    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put on some code here?

Comment: Please let me know what else information I should add

Comment: can you please go through this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881453/the-model-used-to-open-the-store-is-incompatible-with-the-one-used-to-create-the

Comment: Thanks, i did delete it and relaunch. but it didn't work. and so for creating the new version of it. i could not find the place where  Versioned core data model is.